# What is the formula for calculating the distance between two points of an equilateral triangle with a known "radius"?

Tags: geometry, triangles

I have an equilateral triangle with each point being a known distance of N units from the center of the triangle.

What formula would I need to use to determine the length of any side of the triangle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**

let $L$ be the length of the triangle sides.

then

$$L^2=N^2+N^2-2N.N.\cos(\frac{2\pi}{3})$$

and

$$L=2N\sin(\frac{\pi}{3})=N\sqrt{3}$$

Comment: So if my known N was 40, then I would plug 40 into your formula and get L = 40 * Sqrt(3) = 69.2820Gibberish. Awesome; thanks.

Comment: @Will Yes man.$\sqrt{3}\approx 1.7321$. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

First draw the lines from all three points to the center point of this triangle, then notice that two if these lines make an isosceles triangle with angles $2\pi/3$, $\pi/6$, and $\pi/6$. Since we're given the length of two of the sides of this triangle, and the angles are known, we can calculate the length of the third side

Let $a$ denote the length of the inradius, and $b$ the sidelength if the triangle. Then, by the cosine law, we have

$b^2 = a^2 + a^2 - 2aa\cos(2\pi/3)$

$= 2a^2(1 - \cos(2\pi/3)$

$= 2a^2(3/2) $

So we have $b = \sqrt(3a^2)$ or $\sqrt3a$

Answer (score 1):

If you label the triangle $ABC$ (from bottom left to right and top point $C$). Take the center to be $M$. Then consider the triangle formed by $AM$ and the middle of $AB:=Q$.
So now you have $AMQ$ with angle $AMQ = 90$ degrees, and angle $MAQ = 60$ degrees.
This means you have a $1:2:\sqrt{3}$ triangle with $|AM|=N$.
This should be enough to solve it.